# Why isn't ullong a valid kernel module parameter type in Red Hat 7?

Tags: linux, types, parameters, kernel

I've been dancing around with Intel Non-Transparent Bridge hardware and discovered that the ntb_hw_intel driver is not included in Red Hat 7.

From what I can tell, the driver does not build the way it is written - there are module parameters defined as ullong, which is unambiguous in both 32- and 64-bit kernels as a 64-bit object. The driver can be made to build (and load and run) with  RHEL 7.4 by changing references to "ullong" to "ulong" (which is the same type in a  64-bit kernel), except that the build whinges about invalid pointer types; the code attempts to stick the ulong * into a u64 *, which in a 64-bit kernel is defined as unsigned long long. It builds and loads and runs, but it builds ugly.

From what I can tell, the root problem is the moduleparam.h header does not define a "ullong" parameter type. Why is this?

Comment: "the root problem is the moduleparam.h header does not define a "ullong" parameter type." - Probably, they assume that `long long` parameter isn't very popular. In any case, you may easily declare the parameter of any type you need. You just need to provide read and write functions for that. Look for implementation of [STANDARD_PARAM_DEF](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/ident/STANDARD_PARAM_DEF) macro in the  `kernel/params.c` source file.

Comment: I'm not in a position to modify the kernel itself. I'm just looking for arguments to support my justification of the u64 cast warnings that result from mucking around in this particular driver.

Comment: This is not a modification of the kernel core. You can add "ullong" argument just for the module you need. No needs to modify `kernel/params.c` source, I referenced it only as an example of defining kernel parameters.